# Почему сигмой называют крутого человека?

Tags: этимология

Сигма это буква или диван в видео её.Тогда почему сейчас сигмой называют человека,поступающего правильно?

Comment: Есть такой раздел поведенческой зоопсихологии, называется этология, изучает повадки животных в естественных условиях. Вот ученые этологи стали изучать, скажем, поведение волков в стае, оказалось, что у стаи есть вожак, есть особи поддерживающие вожака, а есть всякие отщепенцы, их назвали альфа, бетта и гамма соответственно. Потому пришли женщины психологини и решили подобным образом классифицировать мужиков, оказалось, что мужиков типов чуть больше, ну или дамы не договорились, какой у них мужик круче, ведь каждой хотелось быть с альфой. Тогда решили, что есть ещё сигмы.

Comment: Сигмы, это как альфы, только круче.) Типа босс босса, начальник начальника, президент президента и тп.